# Getting AttributeError: 'SGD' object has no attribute 'defaults' in SimSwap Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, default, attributeerror, sgd

I'm new to using python and code based programming language, but I'm trying to branch out by using Colab programs in an effort to understand a little of the application.  I've been using [this Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/neuralchen/SimSwap/blob/main/SimSwap%20colab.ipynb#scrollTo=wwJOwR9LNKRz) for a little while (I don't have a GPU that can run it locally atm), but recently it began giving me this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-46a887c84c9b> in <module>
     14 
     15 torch.nn.Module.dump_patches = True
---> 16 model = create_model(opt)
     17 model.eval()
     18 

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py in __setstate__(self, state)
     82         self.__dict__.update(state)
     83         self._hook_for_profile()  # To support multiprocessing pickle/unpickle.
---> 84         self.defaults.setdefault('differentiable', False)
     85 
     86     def __repr__(self):

AttributeError: 'SGD' object has no attribute 'defaults'
```

I'm trying to understand if it's a matter of changing the code or a version issue.  Is this fixable on my end or do I need to wait for a version update (or to run back to a previous version?)

I found someone [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/retinanet-examples/issues/77) that was getting a similar error, but didn't really understand his fix.  I tried erasing line 16 to the end of the cell, but those obviously need to be there to some extent.  I researched "SGD", but didn't get very far before I realized there are a lot of "attributeError"s to choose from so came here hoping that I could get some insight into the problem with this code (or maybe myself. lol)

Thank you for helping out a newbie.

Guts

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: as of now feb 22
place this line of code first on the installation cell, run it

!pip3 install torch==1.9.1+cu111 torchvision==0.10.1+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.1 torchtext==0.10.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

then restart your runtime and its good to go

Answer (score 0):

I am a new user. I found an answer that fixes the problem. I hope it helps.

https://github.com/neuralchen/SimSwap/issues/357

user name: amfapic

You should try previous pytorch versions (< 1.13):

pip install torch==1.8.1+cu111 torchvision==0.9.1+cu111 torchaudio==0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Comment: Contents of links must be summarized in stackoverflow answers

Answer (score -1):

```
!pip3 install torch==1.9.1+cu111 torchvision==0.10.1+cu111 torchaudio==0.9.1 torchtext==0.10.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
!pip install insightface==0.2.1 onnxruntime moviepy
!pip install googledrivedownloader
!pip install --upgrade "imageio>=2.5"
```

replace with these

Comment: "replace with these"—can you explain this, please?